# numlist and bullist add <br> on save TinyMCE

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm on a project where I need to use TinyMCE for textarea in wordpress.
The problem is when I save my code, TinyMCE add `<br>` around tags like `<ol>` or `<ul>` and I don't know how to fix that 
There is my code for tinyMCE and the result I have :

```
tinymce.init({ selector:'.tiny',
plugins: "lists, link, paste",
menubar: false,
branding: false,
paste_as_text: true,
toolbar: "formatselect | bold italic | numlist bullist | blockquote | alignleft aligncenter alignright | link | removeformat | indent | outdent | undo redo",
forced_root_block : false,
force_br_newlines : true,
force_p_newlines : false,
lists_indent_on_tab: false,
fix_list_elements : false,
forced_root_block : ''
 });
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSb9t.png)

Comment: You have configured TinyMCE to use `br` and not `p` tags so every time you press `Enter` you get a `br` tag.  It would appear to be working as you have it configured.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need more informations so there is :

1) Before I saved the page :

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMO90.png)

2) After the save :

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPKui.png)

I really don't know why it does this...

Answer (score 0):

```
forced_root_block : false,
force_br_newlines : true,
force_p_newlines : false,
```

These three lines are causing this behavior.